# Stadium has no light

Tags: fifa-13

I installed FIFA 13 yesterday and everything was OK.
But today when i started to playing there is no light in stadiums and players are playing in darkness.

I thought it could be because of `Vsync` so tried to disable it but even changing `Frame rate` did not solve them problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing this patch will solve the problem and a lot of other problems.

http://www.moddingway.com/file/29474.html